# Non-Conservative System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the concept of a conservative system mathematically. A problem in a textbook (Arnold's Mathematical Methods for Classical Mechanics) is asking me to give an example of a non-conservative system, which I've attempted to provide in the following way.

So, given that 
\begin{equation}\ddot{\textbf{x}}=\textbf{f}(\textbf{x})|\textbf{x}\in E^2
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\ddot{\textbf{x}}=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial \textbf{x}}
\end{equation}
Is the function
\begin{equation}\textbf{f}(\textbf{x})=\dot{\textbf{x}}
\end{equation}
an equation describing a non-conservative system?

Please provide an explanation as well.